# Larabook Auth::check() not working

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys i have a problem with codeception,
it isn't working correctly and i'm using all the same code
that there is the videos about larabook from scratch
This is my code in signUpCept.php

```
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->am('a guest');
$I->wantTo('Sign up for a Larabook account');

$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click('Sign Up!');
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/register');

$I->fillField('Username:', 'JohnDoe');
$I->fillField('Email:', 'john@example.com');
$I->fillField('Password:', 'demo');
$I->fillField('Password Confirmation:', 'demo');

$I->click('Sign Up');

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('');
$I->see('Welcome to Larabook!');

$I->seeRecord('users',[
    'username' => 'JohnDoe',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'password' => 'demo'
]);

$I->assertTrue(Auth::check());
```

This is my RegistrationController.php

```
class RegistrationController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Show a form to register the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('registration.create');
    }


    /**
     * Creating a new Larbook user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store() 
    {
        $user = User::create(

            Input::only('username', 'email', 'password')

        );

        Auth::login($user);

        return Redirect::home();
    }


}
```

And this is the error i'm getting

```
Functional Tests (1) ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sign up for a larabook account (SignUpCept)                                                            Fail
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 6.04 seconds, Memory: 25.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) Failed to sign up for a larabook account in SignUpCept (tests/functional/SignUpCept.php)

 Step  I assert true false
 Fail  Failed asserting that false is true.

Scenario Steps:

 13. $I->assertTrue(false) at tests/functional/SignUpCept.php:28
 12. $I->seeRecord("users",{"username":"JohnDoe","email":"john@example.com","password":"demo"}) at tests/functional/SignUpCept.php:26
 11. $I->see("Welcome to Larabook!") at tests/functional/SignUpCept.php:20
 10. $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals("") at tests/functional/SignUpCept.php:19
 9. $I->click("Sign Up") at tests/functional/SignUpCept.php:17
 8. $I->fillField("Password Confirmation:","demo") at tests/functional/SignUpCept.php:15


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 4, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Auth::check()`, keep in mind here you have **two instances**, one for codeception and other for the application being tested.

This means you are trying to `Auth::check()` into the codeception instance, which is useless for you.

You must rely on the [Laravel5](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5) module and use `seeAuthentication()` to replicate your intent.